# ~/.bashrc displays entries depending on how it is called

Tags: bash, environment-variables, bashrc

I am trying to export a new directory "foo" to $PATH using a shell script. For now I used a shell script install.sh that exports the path like this:

```
<install.sh> 
#! /bin/sh

echo export PATH=$PATH:<path/foo> >> ~/.bashrc
```

For some reason, if I now try to display the ~/.bashrc file, I do get different outputs depending on how I print it. For example, accessing it in a Terminal via `vi ~/.bashrc` will display the file without my exported line. However, if I load it via a shell script (the same command but in a .sh file), my exported line is shown. I have no other way to see this line, except through this method. I already checked different versions of the command with different shebangs (bin/sh vs bin/bash) and with/without sudo. Where is my added line stored? I already checked /etc/skel/.bashrc and ~/.bashrc.

(I know that it adds a new export line every time the script gets called. Using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS).

EDIT:

calling the `install.sh` script with sudo script sets the $PATH variable as root and calling it as user returns the user $PATH variable as user which caused this behaviour.

Comment: Do you run the terminal command and the script as the same user?

Comment: Type the command `echo ~` directly in your terminal, and then run the same command in a shell script. See if there is a difference in the directory name that is printed.

Comment: Thank you for the quick help. This seems to resolve the issue. The script set the $PATH variable as root and calling it as user returns the user $PATH variable.